# How can I restore my deleted web.config file

Tags: azure

I'm using `Sitecore 9.1.1` on `Azure environment`,

I'm facing a pretty big problem the `Web.config` has been replaced and I don't know where can I get the file from? Can someone please give me this file if it's the same in all Azure environments or advice me what to do, please.

Comment: Can’t you just install another new instave and take this file from there?

Comment: You could just extract it from the wdp used for deployment, download it from https://dev.sitecore.net/

Answer (score 1):

The download page for Sitecore 9.1.1 is at dev.sitecore.net (as mentioned by @jammykam in his comments): https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/91/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_91_Update1.aspx

From here you have multiple options for how to obtain a clean version of the Web.config:

1. **ZIP archive of the Sitecore site root folder:** This has the Web.config file in it, but is typically meant for on-premise installation. You did not mention if it is PaaS or IaaS, but if IaaS this might be easiest.
2. **Packages for XM or XP:** Make sure to look at the Download options for Azure AppService and extract a Web.config from here if you are trying to replace PaaS Web.config.